# How to remove blank line on top of <code> block

Tags: css

I am getting code from server in next format:

```
<code class="bigCodeBlock">
import std.stdio;
void main() 
{
    writeln("Hello world!");
}
</code>
```

I can't fix code on server. I need to remove empty line break in result html on top of my code.

My css is next:

```
.bigCodeBlock
{
    background-color: #F7F4F4;
    display:block;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it a padding or an empty line? Check it via Inspect Element and let us know.

Comment: I do not have *any* padding property in css.

Answer (score 0):

Change your HTML.

```
<code class="bigCodeBlock">import std.stdio;
void main() 
{
    writeln("Hello world!");
}
</code>
```

`white-space: pre-wrap` will preserve whitespace including linebreaks.

Comment: I thought that it will be good, but I am getting code from server is this format. All I can do is use css.